# Finding the letter in a String entered with a parameter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm learning darts and was wondering how you can get letters inside a String. for example; A word will be given and the function will find how many letters "e" there are.

I'm learning darts and was wondering how you can get letters inside a String. for example; A word will be given and the function will find how many letters "e" there are.d

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `split` function of `String` to make a list of `characters` in the string.

```
String word = "Cheese";
var characterList = word.split("");
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<characterList.length;i++){
  if(characterList[i] == 'e'){
    count+=1;
  }
}
print("number of e in $word is $count");
```

Output

```
number of e in Cheese is 3
```